# Returning null from findOne() when document exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nodemon, mongodb-atlas

Running locally, but accessing an atlas MongoDb DB online, I have builder's data as follows:

```
 [
   {
   "_id": "5ec63e97516541c07c2b26d3",
   "name": "Bob"
   },

  {
  "_id": "5ec64261b9be7b08cb8d7ba9",
  "name": "builder post test"
  }
]
```

Really simple, but the problem is when I'm defining my CRUD actions: I want to be able to get a specific builder, say Bob, from his id above. My code is in my server.js file is as follows:

```
server.get("/:id", (request, response) => {
      const itemId = request.params.id;

      dbCollection.findOne({id: itemId }, (error, result) => {
         if (error) throw error;
         response.json(result);
      });
   });
```

Whenever I test the endpoint: http://localhost:4000/5ec63e97516541c07c2b26d3

I get null returned. I've console logged and made sure id is correct coming in. I've even changed id --> _id to match the schema but still null.

I can access the endpoint  http://localhost:4000/Bob when I changed the findOne initial parameter of id above to name:

```
server.get("/:id", (request, response) => {
          const itemId = request.params.id;

          dbCollection.findOne({name: itemId }, (error, result) => {
             if (error) throw error;
             response.json(result);
          });
       });
```

I'm stumped as to why name works but id doesn't,  I feel like I've missed something basic, any help or advice appreciated!

Comment: are you using mongoose?

Comment: Nope, I'm using mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using mongodb native drive you need to cast to ObjectID first.

```
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

exports.findUserById = (req, res, next) => {
    db.get().collection('user').findOne({ _id: new ObjectId(req.params.id) }).then((result) => {
        if (result === null) {
            res.status(404).json({ errors: [{location: "users", msg: "Not found", param: req.params.id}]})
        }
        req.usuario = result;
        next()
    }).catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).json({ errors: [{location: "users", msg: err, param: req.params}]})
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The way I understood it, I saw it as a string so figured it could be passed in as a string.  Tried to upvote, but unfortunately don't have enough karma yet!

Comment: Why does mongodb native drive need to be an objectId to be accessed rather than a string?

Comment: Well, it is not a string, it is a 12-byte hexadecimal number. So you have to cast it before use. More information here. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/